# Hibernate Auto_Increment

Tags: java, hibernate

Имею в БД таблицу со столбцом id(auto increment).
После удаления данных из таблицы в runtime, требуется сбросить id на 0.

В SQL запросе это делается так - ALTER TABLE 'Table_Name' AUTO_INCREMENT=0.
Но в HQL запросе:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("ALTER TABLE Table_Name AUTO_INCREMENT=0");
```

выдает  QuerySyntaxException.
Как надо написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session.createSQLQuery("ALTER TABLE Table_Name AUTO_INCREMENT=0").executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [createSQLQuery(String queryString)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-)